# I want change the sound value during the processing before play it back

Tags: python, audio, playback, pyaudio

Im recording a signal in real time, and play it back immediately. However, 
I want change the sound value during the processing before play it back.
and here is my code:

```
    import pyaudio
    import time
    import numpy 
    import sys
    import sounddevice as sd


    WIDTH = 2
    CHANNELS = 2
    RATE = 44100
    chunk=1024

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):



   return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

   stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            frames_per_buffer=chunk,
            input=True,
            output=True,
            stream_callback=callback)






      stream.start_stream()

      while stream.is_active():
      time.sleep(0.1)

      stream.stop_stream()
      stream.close()

      p.terminate()
```

I found this code, but I have a problem by connecting my code by that code,can some one show me how can I solve this problem

```
   # This function changes the volume of a sound
   # A factor > 1 increases the volume
   # A factor < 1 decreases the volume
   def changeVolume(sound, factor):
   newSound = duplicateSound(sound)
   for sample in getSamples(newSound):
   value = getSampleValue(sample)
   setSampleValue(sample, value * factor)
   return newSound
```

Comment: A sample is a combination of volume and signal angle. Direct multiplication isn't going to work. Not sure how to accomplish it but you would need to get the angle of the sample and then multiply that by your sound.

Comment: Do you just want to change the volume by a constant amount (not changing over time) or do you want to do more fancy processing?

Comment: @Matthias I want change the value over time

Comment: In your `callback()` function, you'll have to multiply all values of `in_data` with an appropriate number. Since PyAudio provides raw bytes, you'll have to convert to proper numbers first. If you want to avoid this, you can switch to the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module (full disclosure: I'm its author), which directly supports NumPy arrays. If you want to change the multiplication factor over time, you should try to progressively change the value in small steps, otherwise you might hear clicks when changing the volume in one big step.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also have a look at http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/.